# why i can't import maven jar from local repository?

Tags: java, maven

demo1 project is a springboot project,demo project is a springboot project too.
I write a Java Class Test.java in demo1:

```
package com.example.demo1;
public class Test {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("11111111111111");
    }
}
```

and install it on local maven repository:

```
mvn install:install-file "-DgroupId=com.example" "-DartifactId=demo1" "-Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" "-Dpackaging=jar" "-Dfile=target/demo1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

In demo project, l make a dependency of demo1 project,the content of
pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo1</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

when I build demo project,something error happened:

```
mvn clean package
```

the error message is here:

```
com.example.demo1 does not exists
Test cannot find symbol!
```

Comment: are you able to see 'demo1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar' in .m2 folder?

Comment: demo1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar does exists in my ~/.m2 folder !

Comment: If this jar is not present in your m2 folder, you need to install it properly.

Comment: but it is present

Comment: In order to make spring boot as a jar you need to add plugin not just like simple java project IMO .

Comment: check this link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-dependency

Comment: What does your import statement look like?

Answer (score 4):

Probably you're using `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to create a runnable spring boot application artifact. This plugin creates an artifact that indeed has an extension *.jar but in fact its not a jar at all: it has all the dependencies in `BOOT-INF/lib`, it uses special entries in manifest, and so on. Java (JVM) cannot read this jar, spring boot application uses a special class-loader to read this structure which is fairly unique to spring boot applications.

If you want to see what I'm talking about - just open up the JAR of spring boot application with WinRAR/WinZIP or whatever and you'll see it yourself.

That's why in general you can't really make a dependency on a spring boot application.

Now, having said that, there are workarounds:

1. The chances are that you don't really need to be dependent on the whole application, but rather on some "common" code - in this case consider refactoring it to the separate module and make both applications dependent on this module.
2. Use [This link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-dependency) for workaround at the level of plugin configurations in maven, you'll end up with additional jars that might do what you want.

Comment: it is the problem of spring-boot-maven-plugin. delete the  spring-boot-maven-plugin and it does work. Thank you so much!

Comment: It works but it doesn't create a spring boot application at the first place. How will you run it now? That's why I've mentioned two directions that allow both application creation in the spring boot format and the dependency

Comment: it is still a springboot application without dependency of spring-boot-maven-plugin